# Laplace Challenge in One Examples, Is there any help?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, polar-coordinates, laplacian, triangulation

this question is taken from 2014 exam on CE Entrance Exam, [Question $32$ on the end of page $6$](http://parseh.ac.ir/konkor94/modiriat/soal/512-c.pdf).

Consider the Laplace equation of following polar coordination,

### $$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r})+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \theta^2} =0 $$

and the boundary condition:

$$u(a,\theta)=\begin{cases}2\theta & 0<\theta<\pi\\0 & \pi<\theta<2\pi\end{cases}$$

> Calculate the values of $U(0, \theta)$?

**Update: this comes from my idea:**

$$ U(0, \theta)= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} 2 \theta d\theta  + \frac{1}{\pi}  \int 0 \times d \theta =  \frac{\pi^2}{\pi} = \pi$$

> is there any expert describe in shot that how this value $U(0,
> \theta)=2\pi$ is find? or maybe this is wrong answer? how we can
>   calculate this value in brief?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42883/discussion-on-question-by-mokholia-pokholia-laplace-challenge-in-one-examples-i).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ridiculous, comments are for clarifying the questions and discussing of the possible answers

Comment: @user1952009: That comment was generated by the system software. It is an automated response when a moderator is summoned to the scene to purge a **long** chain of comments.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen then you agree it isn't adapted to MSE where long discussion are the only way for making progress

Comment: @user1952009 Occasionally they are, and then I will deal with the flag differently (or wait for a while before doing anything). In the present case only the OP had been posting for the last couple of hours, and their comments were pleas to others to post. That was not progress. I would not halt an ongoing discussion this way. Besides, you can still find all the comments in the chat. Another thing I also consider is that none of the constructive comments were upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem $\Delta u = 0$ for $x \in B(0,a)$ subject to $u=\begin{cases} 2 \theta & 0<\theta<\pi \\ 0 & \pi<\theta<2 \pi \end{cases}$ for $x \in \partial B(0,a)$ satisfies $u(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} u(a,\theta) d \theta = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^\pi 2 \theta d \theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$. This follows from the mean value property of the Laplace equation.

Note that for a discontinuous BC one must be a bit careful about the exact sense of this solution. Still, for the "right" sense of solution, the mean value property holds. One (unnecessarily elaborate) way to view the solution which gives this result is $u(x)=E_x[f(W_\tau)]$ where $f$ is the solution on the boundary, $W$ is a Wiener process, $E_x$ is expectation over Wiener paths started at $x$, and $\tau$ is the first time for a Wiener path to hit $\partial B(0,a)$. Then for $x=0$, $W_\tau$ is uniformly distributed on the circle, giving the result.

Comment: I agree with your answer.

Comment: a Wiener process ??? why ? did you mean as a way to regularize the mean value property in the case of a non integrable boundary ?

Comment: @user1952009 The formula I gave for the "probabilistic" solution to the Laplace equation holds in the classical situation where the boundary is smooth and the boundary function is continuous. It follows from the mean value property and elementary properties of the Wiener process.

Comment: (Cont.) In the nonclassical situation you should use a little bit more machinery to make sense of the equation. Probability theory does not have to be that machinery, but it is one way. Classical potential theory is another way (with essentially the same results). Distribution theory is another (with weaker results but more general tools).

Comment: @Ian you didn't answer to what I asked : you meant to generalize $f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(a+ e^{it}) dt$ to the case where $f( e^{it})$ is not integrable ? Then the most obvious way is $f(a) = \lim_{r \to 1^-}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(a+r e^{it}) dt$ since an harmonic function is discontinuous only on its boundary

Comment: @user1952009 1. This does the same thing, and also works the same with a much more pathological boundary. I didn't say my approach was the most obvious. 2. It is not immediately obvious how to connect the values of the *solution* near the boundary to the values of the *given boundary function* without knowing something about the set of points at which the solution approaches the boundary function from inside the domain.

Comment: @user1952009 To be a bit more specific, for a given Dirichlet problem (which we think of as being parametrized by the domain $U$ and the boundary function $f$), there is a question about the points $x$ on the boundary such that if $u$ is the Perron solution to the Dirichlet problem then $\lim_{y \to x} u(y)=f(x)$ when we take limits from inside $U$. Provided this set of points has full measure (in the sense of some appropriate measure on the boundary), your formula makes sense. It can happen that it *doesn't* have full measure, in which case you have a more serious problem.

Comment: I understand nothing.  if $f$ is harmonic on $\Omega = \{|z-a| < 1\}$, then $f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(a+r e^{it}) dt, r < 1$ is always true, and so is $f(a) = \lim_{r \to 1-} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(a+r e^{it}) dt$. The problem is to switch $\lim$ and $\int$ so that $f(a) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(a+e^{it}) dt$, and this is where in general viewing $f_{\mid\partial \Omega}$ as the distribution $\langle f_{\mid\partial \Omega} ,\varphi \rangle =\lim_{r \to 1^-} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(a+r e^{it}) \varphi(t) dt$ is required.

Comment: You're obfuscating the notation a little bit by using $f$ for the solution while I am using it for the boundary function. The point is to express the solution in terms of the boundary function, not in terms of itself. Yes, $u(0)=\lim_{r \to a^-} A(r)$ where $A(r)$ is the average of $u$ over the circle of radius $r$. But that expresses the solution in terms of itself. This only has anything to do with the boundary function if the solution approaches the boundary function "enough", which does not always happen (even if we assume the boundary function is continuous).

Comment: Thanks @Ian the other answer is removed, I think your answer is correct.